# STS: arm64-v8a CtsSecurityBulletinHostTestCases fail

Tags: sts

After updating the security patch, the test failed. Check that systemui has been patched.
java.lang.AssertionError: on-device tests failed:
android.security.cts.CVE_2023_40120.DeviceTest#testPocCVE_2023_40120:
Device is vulnerable to b/274775190 hence foreground services can be started with an empty notification
expected to be false
at android.security.cts.CVE_2023_40120.DeviceTest.testPocCVE_2023_40120(DeviceTest.java:143)

```
at com.android.tradefed.testtype.junit4.BaseHostJUnit4Test.runDeviceTests(BaseHostJUnit4Test.java:749)
at com.android.tradefed.testtype.junit4.BaseHostJUnit4Test.runDeviceTests(BaseHostJUnit4Test.java:648)
at com.android.tradefed.testtype.junit4.BaseHostJUnit4Test.runDeviceTests(BaseHostJUnit4Test.java:591)
at com.android.tradefed.testtype.junit4.BaseHostJUnit4Test.runDeviceTests(BaseHostJUnit4Test.java:537)
at com.android.tradefed.testtype.junit4.BaseHostJUnit4Test.runDeviceTests(BaseHostJUnit4Test.java:357)
at com.android.tradefed.testtype.junit4.BaseHostJUnit4Test.runDeviceTests(BaseHostJUnit4Test.java:313)
at android.security.cts.CVE_2023_40120.testPocCVE_2023_40120(CVE_2023_40120.java:40)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:61)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
```

...
Has the [patch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d26544e5a4fd554b790b4d0c5964d9e95d9e626b%5E%21/#F0) been applied but the test still fails?
I have no idea at all, please help me.